# Generate Hierarchy value automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a tree table with column `ID`, `ParentID` and `Hierarchy` and want to generate `Hierarchy` column value dependent by `ParentID`. for this purpose I use triggers. do exists better way to generate Hierarchy column value?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [TR_MyTable_BeforInsert] ON [MyTable]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
Declare @Name NVarChar(100),
        @ParentID Int

Declare DACategory Cursor For
Select  A.Name, A.ParentID
From    Inserted A
OPEN    DACategory
FETCH NEXT FROM DACategory INTO @Name, @ParentID
While @@FETCH_STATUS=0 Begin

    Insert Into MyTable (Name, ParentID, Hierarchy)
    Values (@Name, @ParentID, dbo.F_MyTableGetHID(NULL, @ParentID))

    FETCH NEXT FROM DACategory INTO @Name, @ParentID
End
Close   DACategory
Deallocate DACategory
END
```

Function :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [F_MyTableGetHID]
(
    @ID int,
    @ParentID int
)
RETURNS HierarchyID

AS BEGIN
    Declare @RootHID HierarchyID, 
            @LastHID HierarchyID

    IF (@ParentID IS NULL)Begin
        Set @RootHID = HierarchyID::GetRoot()
        Select @LastHID = Max(Hierarchy) From MyTable Where ParentID IS NULL
    End Else Begin
        Select @RootHID = Hierarchy From MyTable Where ID = @ParentID
        select @LastHID = Max(Hierarchy) From MyTable where ParentID = @ParentID
    End
    return @RootHID.GetDescendant(@LastHID, NULL)
END
```

for Update this table also have trigger to set Hierarchy column again when `ParentID` Changed.

**what's the best practices for this problem?**

**EDIT 1** : I look up solution that not use trigger if possible.

Comment: This question is a bit difficult to answer based on the description, so rather than attempting to answer it directly, I will suggest that I have had some performance boosts over CURSORs by using either "common table expressions" (often called cte's) or use of memory based tables. Since I am unfamiliar with the kind of data you are inserting (e.g. how much) and the details of the table you are inserting into (e.g. how big) I can't say if that's the best bet for you or not, but you might want to consider looking into it. You might be able to get some boosts with appropriate indexes too.

Comment: What is Hierarchy? The id of the top element in the list?

Comment: What is `HierarchyID` and `GetDescendant`? Sorry, can you explain this `HierarchyID::GetRoot()` ?

Comment: so did my suggestion helped you?

Comment: @mehdi_lotfi What is the point of setting a bounty when your question is almost incomprehensible? Hardly anyone understand's your code. Answer the question RGI and I asked you. Making your question understandable is much more effective than any bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a different approach to answer both the questions. I generally avoid using triggers until it is the last choice as it adds un-necessary overhead on the database.

Comparision between triggers and stored procedure

- It is easy to view table relationships , constraints, indexes, stored
  procedure in database but triggers are difficult to view.
- Triggers execute invisible to client-application application. They
  are not visible or can be traced in debugging code.
- It is easy to forget about triggers and if there is no documentation
  it will be difficult to figure out for new developers for their
  existence.
- Triggers run every time when the database fields are updated and it
  is overhead on system. It makes system run slower.

Enough said, this is why I prefer stored procs. You can create a job file (say for ex : it executes after every 30 min, or any other time) via agent. You can use the logic for insertion in that job file. In this way your data in the `tree table` would be near to real time.

now reference to create an agent :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191128(v=sql.90).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You asked for the best practice.

The best practice is not to use the adjacency list model (which is what you have) and instead switch to the nested set model.

It's more difficult to code and understand, which is why it's not as popular, but it's much more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

### You should use Trigger without Cursors in this context

```
ALTER TRIGGER [TR_MyTable_BeforInsert] ON [MyTable]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Insert Into MyTable (Name, ParentID, Hierarchy)
    Select Name, ParentID, dbo.F_MyTableGetHID(NULL, ParentID)
    From inserted
END
```

Comment: I must use cursor. because to calculate Hierarchy for each record, must be parent record hierarchy calculated.

Comment: The functionality that Cursor is offering in the form of Iteration is happening  in one shot as mentioned in this post. Let me know in case of any confusion..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that calculates the hierarchyid value, given the foreign-key to the parent. Then you can call this function as the default value calculator for the column. If you prevent the users from inserting into this column, the default value will always apply.

This solution will work, only if the parent-child relationship is not updatable.

Comment: Well, it turns out that you can't use a column as the input parameter of a UDF in default value binding... Sorry, what can I do to return the bounty?

Answer (score 0):

No need for cursor

just use

```
Insert Into MyTable (Name, ParentID, Hierarchy) 
 select Name, ParentID, dbo.F_MyTableGetHID(NULL, ParentID)   
  from inserted
```

Can you explain function - not sur what its doing.  But looks like it could be turned into a query and therefore could be combined with above - best practice is always do set theory on relational databases