# Convert tree table from source database to destination database using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I use `SSIS` for convert data from old database to new database. I use below solution for convert tree source table to tree target table.

FIRST: convert all data from source to destination

Second: set `ParentID` column in destination table according to source `ParentID' column in source table.

Source table structure is :

```
TbSource (ID int, ParentID int, Name NVarchar(50))
```

Destination table structure is :

```
TbDestination (ID int,  ParentID int, Name NVarChar(50), HID Hierarchy, OldID int)
```

- Step 1 : I convert all data from `TbSource` to `TbDestination` with NULL value for ParentID.
- Step 2 : Update `ParentID` of `TbDestination` according to `OldID` column and `TbSource` table.

I have trigger on TbDestination for calculate HID Column. [Can see hear](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11381537/1407421).

I look up for better way to convert data that convert in one step.

Source Database and Destination Database are `SQL Server 2008 R2`

Comment: whats the problem you see eith this approach? Doesnt it work?

Comment: I look for better solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use following steps in order to solve my problem:

**Step 1:** I convert all data from TbSource to TbDestination with NULL value for ParentID.

**Step 2:** Update ParentID of TbDestination according to OldID column and TbSource table